# Wordpress - AMP validator FAIL - NextGen Gallery

Tags: wordpress, amp-html, nextgen-gallery, google-amp

I’m using Google AMP for my press site.

But I had many validation error.
I found on the internet, it’s maybe one plugin which can cause this error, so I had checked all my plugins and finally I discovered that it’s NextGen gallery which break my validation.

I contact the support but no response.

ERRORS :

```
> The mandatory attribute 'amp-custom' is missing in tag 'style
> amp-custom'. DISALLOWED_HTML line 256, column 0    The attribute
> 'href' in tag 'link rel=stylesheet for fonts' is set to the invalid
> value
> 'http://ns3363707.ip-94-23-251.eu/cosavostra/dev/tennismagazine_2/wp-content/themes/citynews/inc/shortcodes/css/shortcodes.css'.
> AUTHOR_STYLESHEET_PROBLEM line 270, column 0    The tag 'script' is
> disallowed except in specific forms. CUSTOM_JAVASCRIPT_DISALLOWED line
> 311, column 72    The tag 'script' is disallowed except in specific
> forms. CUSTOM_JAVASCRIPT_DISALLOWED line 312, column 0    The tag
> 'script' is disallowed except in specific forms.
> CUSTOM_JAVASCRIPT_DISALLOWED line 314, column 0    The tag 'script' is
> disallowed except in specific forms. CUSTOM_JAVASCRIPT_DISALLOWED line
> 318, column 0    The tag 'script' is disallowed except in specific
> forms. CUSTOM_JAVASCRIPT_DISALLOWED line 348, column 0    The tag
> 'script' is disallowed except in specific forms.
> CUSTOM_JAVASCRIPT_DISALLOWED line 349, column 0    The tag 'script' is
> disallowed except in specific forms. CUSTOM_JAVASCRIPT_DISALLOWED line
> 350, column 0
```

Can I have some alternative Or advice to fix this ?

Comment: Can you provide more information what exactly fails? I assume the **<img>** tag becasue it's not converted into a **<amp-img>** tag, right?

Comment: Hello, I edited my post with errors. The validation is Ok when I desactivate this plugin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem with this line to add to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'run_ngg_resource_manager', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Here's a slightly different solution: https://gist.github.com/westonruter/99b1ca0d593f44888401a396d991e3a6